# Can I use a merge field in the "From Address" field of a Mandrill template?

Tags: email, mandrill, mergefield

I want to create Mandrill template that should use different "From Address"'es depending on dynamic data.

Can I use a merge field for this? If not, how should I create a template with a dynamic "From Address".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [their documentation](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/28499087-Can-I-use-merge-tags-in-my-subject-line-or-other-message-headers-), it's not possible to use a merge var in the From Address field for a template.

You'll probably want to handle that logic on your end (i.e. generate the from address dynamically based on whatever criteria you're using) and then pass that address to Mandrill in your API request or SMTP message.